# How to pass MySql Query to ActiveDataProvider in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a mysql Query with joins and it is working perfect. I want to pass the result to Yii2 ActiveDataProvider. 
My Controller code look like

`

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $theme = Theme::find();
        $query = "SELECT t.*,COUNT(d.id) AS total_downloads FROM `themes` AS T 
                            LEFT JOIN downloads AS D 
                            ON D.theme_id = T.id GROUP 
                            by t.id ORDER BY total_downloads DESC LIMIT 6";
            $connection=Yii::$app->db;  
            $trends = $connection->createCommand($query);
            $model = $trends->queryAll();
            $object = (object) $model;
        $ActiveDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $object]);

        return $this->render('trendings',[
                    'ActiveDataProvider'=>$ActiveDataProvider,
                ]);
    }`
```

and View file code `

```
    ListView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $ActiveDataProvider,
        'options' => [
            'tag' => 'div',
            'class' => 'list-wrapper',
            'id' => 'list-wrapper',
        ],
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'first',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'last',
            'prevPageLabel' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>',
            'nextPageLabel' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>',
             'maxButtonCount' => 3,
        ],
        // 'layout' => "{pager}\n{items}\n{summary}",
        'summary' => false,
        'itemView' => '_list',
    ]);
    ?>`
```

Since I have passed QueryAll so ActiveDataProvider is not woking and passing a error "The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses"

Answer (score 0):

U didnt passed `queryAll()`, u passed a result of function `queryAll()`, which is an array of objects. And ure not using this:

```
$theme = Theme::find();
```

Change this:

```
$query = "SELECT t.*,COUNT(d.id) AS total_downloads FROM `themes` AS T 
                            LEFT JOIN downloads AS D 
                            ON D.theme_id = T.id GROUP 
                            by t.id ORDER BY total_downloads DESC LIMIT 6";
```

to:

```
$theme->select = 'YOUR SELECT HERE';
```

Dont use `queryAll()`, just pass `$theme` object as `query` param do `ActiveDataProvider`.

And remove this:

```
        $connection=Yii::$app->db;  
        $trends = $connection->createCommand($query);
        $model = $trends->queryAll();
        $object = (object) $model;
```

Comment: I am so sorry I forgot to mention. I did not use $theme = Theme::find(); yet . I am stuck on below code.

Comment: That's why i told u what u should do.

Comment: As you can see I have used joins so I want to use custom sql query.

Comment: No, u still dont want to use custom sql query. Instead of that use `$theme->joinWith('relationName');` What's the purpose of using framework if u dont use it?

Comment: What is problem with `queryAll()`? Dont use queryAll(), just pass $theme object as query param do ActiveDataProvider.

Comment: I tried to do that but it throw same error I have mentioned above

Comment: how can i use JoinWith to get same result as `$query = "SELECT t.*,COUNT(d.id) AS total_downloads FROM 'themes' AS T 
                            LEFT JOIN downloads AS D 
                            ON D.theme_id = T.id GROUP 
                            by t.id ORDER BY total_downloads DESC LIMIT 6"`

Comment: above query provide me **_total_downloads_** as count so how can i do this with joinWit?

Comment: Prepare query in Yii2 style + define public property in model ('total_downloads' for this case) and it will apear in model as a value of this property.

Comment: `$theme = Theme::find()->joinWith('downloads')->all();` This is my Query  in Yii2 Style and this is public varible `public $total_downloads;` and my relation is `public function getDownloads()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Download::className(),['theme_id'=>'id']);
    }` But it is not working as I need.What can I change here to get total_downloads?

Comment: And wheres `$theme->select = 'YOUR SELECT HERE';` where u can put `count()`? Update MAIN QUESTION with current code, not in comments.

Comment: sure, Thanks for help